# Convert constuction 'she is standing behind B ' to interrogative expression?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to construction expression

> She(A) is standing next to B.
> .
>   in to this interrogative construction .
>   Who is A standing next to?

Now, for the expression

> She is standing behind B.

I don't know what will be construction, when I try to convert the same way.

> Who is she standing behind?

Is this expression correct? If yes, Are these expression right also

> Who is he sitting on top of?
>   or
>   Who is she behind?(for the expression, She is behind B.)

Comment: *Where is she standing?*; *Who is behind B?* - It's her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to be aware of a common "myth" that ending a sentence with a preposition is incorrect grammatically.  Mignon Fogarty has [a nice web article about this](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition) that might be worth reading if you're interested enough...The main reason for concern is that some people may try to correct you, when in fact your examples are right. (And therefore so is @snailplane!) Here's a quote from the last page of the article:

> I said you don’t need to rewrite those sentences, but because of the prevalent myth that it’s wrong to end sentences with prepositions, there are times when you should avoid doing it even though it isn’t wrong. For example, when you’re writing a cover letter to a potential employer, don’t end a sentence with a preposition. The person reading the letter could see it as an error. I always recommend following the most conservative grammar rules in [job applications](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/how-to-write-a-better-resume.aspx). I’d rather be hired than lose out on an opportunity because my grammar was correct--but perceived as wrong.
>
> But once you're hired and you’re in a position to have a discussion about grammar, don’t be afraid to end sentences with prepositions as long as the preposition isn’t unnecessary. Just be ready to show your boss a good [style guide](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/im-so-stylish.aspx) or this Web page and do your part to dispel one of the [top ten grammar myths](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/top-ten-grammar-myths.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all of your examples are correct.